# Value breaks outputted HTML in XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm pretty new to XSLT, and I have trouble with the following:

I would like to have this output:

```
<div class="member">
    <h2><a href="#">The First Firm</a></h2>
    <div class="slidecontent">
        <p>
            Adress:<br>
            The First Firm<br>
            Some Adress 123
        </p>
        <div class="downloadsection">
            Redegørelser og Rapporter/The First Firm/Miljøredegørelse-2011.pdf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="member">
    <h2><a href="#">The Second Firm</a></h2>
    <div class="slidecontent">
        <p>
            Adress:<br>
            The Second Firm<br>
            Some Adress 123
        </p>
        <div class="downloadsection"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My XML looks like this (the first 3 lines is stripped - the editor didn't like them):

```
    <Template>
        <loop name="Rows">
          <item>
             <loop name="Row">
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>FirmName</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value>The First Firm</Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>0</Column.Count>
                </item>
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>FirmAdress</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value>Some Adress 123</Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>1</Column.Count>
                </item>
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>Miljoredegorelse</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value>Redegørelser og Rapporter/The First Firm/Miljøredegørelse-2011.pdf</Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>2</Column.Count>
                </item>
             </loop>
          </item>
          <item>
             <loop name="Row">
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>FirmName</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value>The Second Firm</Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>0</Column.Count>
                </item>
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>FirmAdress</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value>Some Adress 456</Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>1</Column.Count>
                </item>
                <item>
                   <Row.ColumnName>Miljoredegorelse</Row.ColumnName>
                   <Row.Value></Row.Value>
                   <Row.Count>0</Row.Count>
                   <Column.Count>2</Column.Count>
                </item>
             </loop>
          </item>
       </loop>
    </Template>
```

And the XSLT:

```
<xsl:param name="numcolumns" select="3" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Template" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Template">
    <xsl:call-template name="MemberList" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="MemberList">
    <xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Rows']/item[((position() - 1) mod $numcolumns) = 0]">
            <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $numcolumns]">
                <div class="member">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="#">
                        <xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Row']/item">
                            <xsl:if test="Row.ColumnName='FirmName' and string-length(Row.Value)!='0'">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Row.Value" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="slidecontent">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:text>Adress: </xsl:text><br />
                            <xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Row']/item">
                                <xsl:if test="Row.ColumnName='FirmAdress' and string-length(Row.Value)!='0'">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row.Value" /><br />
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </p>

                        <div>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                <xsl:text>downloadsection</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Row']/item">
                                <xsl:if test="Row.ColumnName='Miljoredegorelse' and string-length(Row.Value)!='0'">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row.Value" />
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The output breaks when i'm outputting the Row.Column "Miljoredegorelse" from the second firm.

The Row.Value is displayed correctly  - but somehow the `</div>` afterwards doesn't get out. The first div `<div class="downloadsection">` is made selfclosing somehow and looks like `<div class="downloadsection" />`.

Why is that happening? Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks right to me.  Your `if` condition is testing for

```
Row.ColumnName='Miljoredegorelse' and string-length(Row.Value)!='0'
```

and in the example XML you've posted the `Miljoredegorelse` for the second firm has an empty `Row.Value`, thus failing the right hand side of the `and`.  Thus there are no matching items, no child nodes get output inside that `div`, so the serializer produces an empty element.

If you're producing HTML output then you might get better results if you add

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```

to your stylesheet.  Depending on the processor this might make it use `<div></div>` instead of `<div/>` for empty elements (both forms are identical in XML/XHTML).

---

A point of style, instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Row']/item">
  <xsl:if test="somecondition">
```

you can merge the `if` test into the `for-each` select expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="loop[@name='Row']/item[somecondition]">
```

Technically this is not 100% identical but the difference is only apparent if you use the `position()` function inside the body of the `for-each`, which you are not doing here.

If the only thing inside the `for-each` is an `apply-templates` then you could go even further and eliminate the `for-each` as well:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="loop[@name='Row']/item[
       Row.ColumnName='Miljoredegorelse' and string-length(Row.Value)!='0'
     ]/Row.Value" />
```

Comment: If XSLT 2.0 was being used, then 'xhtml' could be used as the output method, and according to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xhtml-output then <div></div> would have to be output in this case.

Comment: @Ian Roberts - That did the trick! The output should be html. And thank you very much for pointing out the other loop-stuff.

Comment: And @TimC - Actually it is XSLT 2.0, so xhtml is the one i'm using. Thank you.